# A library for tabular output with automatic handling of column width?

Tags: c++, tabular

Does there exist a C++ library that can be used for automating handling of columns' widths in tabular output?

I envision that the library would provide a `tout` object representing a logical (i.e. not on screen) table, so I would be able to write:

```
tout << a << b << std::endl;
```

`a` and `b` would be put into consecutive columns and `std::endl` would end a row. The `tout` object would keep track of the widest entry in each column and enlarge the column width as needed. Then I would be able to send the whole thing to the real output stream:

```
std::cout << tout;
```

This seems to me like a good idea and I would think that such a thing must have been implemented, but I could not find anything of the sorts...

Comment: There probably doesn't exist such a library, and it probably doesn't exist because it's so easy to use [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) like e.g. [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg With `std::setw`, the width has to be pre-computed. Think about a generic logger, where the entries describing the events might possess different length contents. Also, it makes the output statements crowded. It would be nice to not have to care about the width -- that the width would be updated on the fly.

Comment: Why close this question? There have been other questions that seek a library (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10824999/2725810) that were found to be perfectly fitting SO.

Answer (score 2):

How about this for a solution: Create a class with an overloaded `<<` operator that takes any kind of argument (by using templates) and puts that in a collection (like a `std::list` of [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/any.html) nodes).

Then make an overloaded `operator<<(std::ostream&, const your_special_class&)` which call a function in the class to do the formatting into columns and returns a string.

The formatting function can get the width of the terminal, the number of items in the internal collection, and calculate the width of each column. Then it uses `std::ostringstream` with the `std::setw` manipulator to format each column. It returns the column-formatted string.

For extra points, you could make the formatting function to create multi-line columns, by [word-wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15720061/440558) each column. This needs more work as you need to "print" each line of the wrapped output as a single line in the actual output.

Comment: Sure. That is almost exactly what I thought of doing. However, I wanted to make sure that I was not re-inventing a wheel.